# Issue with Let's Encrypt SSL installation on AWS EC2

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm having troubles with installing Let's Encrypt certification on AWS EC2 instance. Followed couple of tutorials from Google. 
I've created the cert files and updated the path correctly in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf. However, my domain is still not accessible via https. I haven't created multiple httpd config files for different domain but configuring them all in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. The typical configuration for a domain looks like following :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mydomain.in
 ServerAlias www.mydomain.in
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 <Directory /var/www/html>
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the similar fashion, I've added multiple domains on the server.  The certificate files I've generated for 1 domain only.

Any help or pointers in resolving the same will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While generating the cetificate you have to mention all the domain at single time.

then you can use the same generated certificate for multiple domains.

For more information please check this link https://blog.alejandrocelaya.com/2016/08/16/setup-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-in-a-aws-elastic-load-balancer/

For multiple domains,you can do this by the creating multiple virtual host with same ssl setting.